# Android: Locking screen orientation sometimes

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have an application that is designed for tablets. It displays one view of its data in portrait mode and a different view of the data in landscape. The user can switch between the two at will.

On a smaller "phone" type device, landscape is too small to be useful, but portrait mode is still viable. I would like to force portrait on a smaller device, say anything under 7, while allowing both modes on tablets.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the developer guidelines for [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). You can then use the sw qualifier to switch on the physical screen size.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, which is preferable to answering the question directly. I believe doing things the right way is always preferable than to hack something together.

Comment: So I have a /layout folder and a /layout-sw600dp-land. Using the emulator with a 480x800 phone, there should be no layout for landscape. Yet when I Ctrl-F11 the phone to landscape, it still tries to switch the display to landscape. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Locking orientation is as simple as using android:screenOrientation="portrait" for the activity in the manifest, but that's not a solution to your problem. It sounds like you need to rethink your layouts for smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Krylez is right and the correct solution is to do something else but in case you want to lock/release screen orientation anyway (I use it together with short running AsyncTasks to avoid having to deal with the ProgressDialog)

```
public class Device {

public static void lockOrientation(Activity activity) {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();
    int tempOrientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    int orientation = 0;
    switch(tempOrientation)
    {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        else
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
        break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        else
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
    }
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
}





public static void releaseOrientation(Activity activity) {
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}

}
```